# Remove string single string with mode_rewrite?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm attempting to redirect URLs containing `full-resolution`.
I'd like to remove it.

This is what I have currently:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} full-resolution
RewriteRule ^(.*)/full-resolution/(.*)$ $1/$2
```

The above results in an empty page.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I'm using [Adaptive Images](http://adaptive-images.com/) to deliver device appropriate images. Adaptive Images works by intercepting image file requests and sending them to a PHP script that works some magic and serves up a smaller sized image. Adaptive Images does what I need it to and works fine.

However, I also need to let users have access to the original, higher resolution image file. I need to create a way to escape Adaptive Images.

Images live in the `/assets/img` directory, like so:

```
/assets/img/foo/bar.jpg
```

The solution I came up with was to include a string within image paths and to have apache simply remove that string.

The resulting URL transformation would happen:

```
/assets/img/full-resolution/foo/bar.jpg

/assets/img/foo/bar.jpg
```

My thought is that the correct image would be found, avoiding Adaptive Images, and thus serving the original high resolution file. Below is the entire script for this vhost.

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin agarritano@localhost
    ServerName pmportal.local
    DocumentRoot /Users/agarritano/pm-portal
    <Directory /Users/agarritano/pm-portal>
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
          RewriteEngine On

          # Add any directories you wish to omit from the Adaptive-Images process on a new line, as follows:
          # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !ignore-this-directory
          # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !and-ignore-this-directory-too

          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !full-resolution

          # don't apply the AI behaviour to images inside AI's cache folder:
          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !ai-cache

          # Send any GIF, JPG, or PNG request that IS NOT stored inside one of the above directories
          # to adaptive-images.php so we can select appropriately sized versions

          RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$ adaptive-images.php

          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} full-resolution
          RewriteRule ^(.*)/full-resolution/(.*)$ $1/$2

        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>.
```

Comment: Post some details about request and actual image paths. And, is this the only rule in your htaccess?

Comment: I've expounded, sorry for the lack of information. I think I originally omitted it for brevity.